# Remap heading commands

Tags: macros, sectioning, pandoc

I am writing a pair of Pandoc template and LaTeX package(s) for my authoring workflow (write in Markdown, produce PDF through Pandoc->LaTeX). In the Markdown document the type of document can be selected, and consequently different document classes can be loaded (book, report, article, presentation, or letter classes).

Unfortunately I can't make Pandoc dynamically adjust the mapping of heading levels to LaTeX commands. So the intermediate LaTeX file will always have `\section{}` as first-level headings, `\subsection{}` as second level etc., as it is appropriate for an article class.

What I *can* do in a Pandoc template is conditionally execute LaTeX commands, so the suggestion was to remap the LaTeX sectioning commands appropriately. My question is: is it possible to "remap" all sectioning commands or do I have to "recreate" them by copying their original definition?

If I do

```
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\part{#1}}
```

it seems to correctly shift chapters to become parts.
However, if I do

```
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\part{#1}}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\chapter{#1}}
```

both sections *and* chapters end up being parts. I can see why this happens, as `\section` is mapped to `\chapter` which is already a `\part` (the order of the two commands doesn't seem to make a difference, which is what I hoped for).

What is the best (only?) way of shifting all heading levels by a fixed number of levels?

Comment: `\let\originalchapter\chapter \renewcommand\chapter{\part} \let\originalsection\section \renewcommand\section{\originalchapter}` But that's not the way of doing this, probably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start from the lowest sectioning level you plan to use:

```
\let\subsubsection\subsection
\let\subsection\section
\let\section\chapter
\let\chapter\part
```

With `\let` one essentially copies the current definition.

Comment: Thank you, that works as desired. Does `\renewcommand` simply reference instead?

Comment: @uli_1973 Yes, `\renewcommand{\section}{\chapter}` will only use the meaning of `\chapter` current at the time `\section` is used, not at the time the redefinition is made.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell `pandoc` to use `part` as the top level with the option `--top-level-division=part`

From [pandoc's user guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers):

> **`--top-level-division=[default|section|chapter|part]`**
>
> Treat top-level headers as the given division type in LaTeX, ConTeXt, DocBook, and TEI output. The hierarchy order is part, chapter, then section; all headers are shifted such that the top-level header becomes the specified type. The default behavior is to determine the best division type via heuristics: unless other conditions apply, `section` is chosen. When the LaTeX document class is set to `report`, `book`, or `memoir` (unless the `article` option is specified), `chapter` is implied as the setting for this option. If `beamer` is the output format, specifying either `chapter` or `part` will cause top-level headers to become `\part{..}`, while second-level headers remain as their default type.

Comment: Thank you, but that's beside the point. Basically I asked about *dynamically* changing the top-level-division from *inside* the template.

Comment: If the point of "dynamically adjust[ing] the mapping of heading levels to LaTeX commands" was to do so at arbitrary places "*inside* the template", then this is, indeed, beside it.